# Many-to-many without join table

Tags: postgresql, orm, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a Template and Comment table.

Template has two fields `ID` and `KEY`, I can have multiple versions of a template with the same `KEY` but different `ID`. For example:

```
ID   1  2  3
KEY  1  1  1
```

And a Comment table with a `ID` column:

```
ID             1  2  3
TEMPLATE_KEY   1  1  1
```

Is it possible to do a many-to-many between Template and Comment like `Template(key) <-> Comment(ID)` without a join table  ?

Comment: Many to many without an extra join table: no, it's not. But the question isn't very intelligible, so maybe rephrase it somewhat -- it looks like you're actually seeking a one-to-many relationship with a versioned piece of data, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

ManyToMany is never possible without an additional table in a relational database. Why would one want to avoid such a table at all?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this but a join table will make referential integrity reasonable to enforce.  You *could* store foreign key arrays on both sides, code triggers to manage them, and the like and if you do a delete, you will have a lot of proboems.....

Now, it is possible that in 9.4, this will be natively supported but it isn't there yet and the patches are still under discussion.  In general though, *usually* it is better to just go through join tables.